# Quitting WPF Application after Window Closed

Tags: c#, wpf, exit

I have a method in class where I call `loginWindow.ShowDialog();` which brings up a Window, however when you press Close (X in top right) it doesn't Quit the application, rather continues to run whatever is below `loginWindow.ShowDialog();` in that method.

How am I able to quit the application entirely if that Window is closed?

I tried to use:

```
    protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }
```

Although this didn't shut the application down, which confuses me. When I was using `loginWindow.Show();` this wasn't a problem.

Comment: What is your shutdown mode?

Comment: I don't think I've defined it? The problem is for only this specific Window do I want to quit the application when Close is pressed. I have other Windows that when close is pressed, I just use Hide(); as I do not want to quit the application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your application runs, based on your sample code I have two solutions.

Solution 1:- Every window has `DialogResult` property. Inside the `OnClosing` event assign `DialogResult = true;` and call the **Shutdown** method. The windows who is responsible to call will get the result from return value of `ShowDialog()` method

For example:-

```
  private void SecondWindow_OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = true;
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
```

Below event, is from the First screen, calling the Second Window.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SecondWindow secondWindow = new SecondWindow();
        var dialogResult = secondWindow.ShowDialog();
        if (dialogResult.HasValue && dialogResult.Value == false)
        {
            // any code of yours which must not be executed after the second
            // window has closed the process
       }
    }
```

Once, the `DialogResult` is assigned **true**, the first window will check only if it is false execute the below code or else ignore.

Solution 2:- We will get the Current Application Running Process and **Kill** the whole process that is your whole application.

```
    private void SecondWindow_OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
    }
```

Comment: @Explorex were my solution relevant to you ? if not could you tell me why it isn't working for you.So that I can think more on this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [shutdown mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.shutdownmode?view=netframework-4.7.2) that you can define in the App.Xaml

The default option is OnLastWindowClosed. If it is OnExplicitShutdown than the application wants you to call Application.Shutdown(). What this means is, if you close all windows the application is still running because it is expecting a Application.Shutdown() to be called. This is an explicit shutdown.

Other two options are implicit meaning the Application.Shutdown() method will be called when the last window is closed or when the main window is closed.

Can you check what option you have defined?

Comment: I didn't define it

Comment: I just tried all three, none of which work application continues to run after this window has been closed

Comment: In that case you probably have some code that is preventig the application to shutdown. If you create a new WPF project you can see how ShutdownMode property works. By default, when you close the last Window the application shuts down. I can think of nothing else that would prevent this behavior by default. Maybe a background worker or something...

Comment: I'm sure it has something to do with me using window.showdialog() rather than window.show()